# Difference between Cache,Session,Application,View in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, caching, view

I want to store some data during my site viewing.

Sometime i need to store large data like crystal reports and some times i need to store a string.

So which is best to use and when to use.
Where are these datas stored. i.e., Client or Server

Comment: What are the use of storing crystal reports and string?

Comment: to display a crystal report in browser, if a crystal report have many pages we have to store in session so that pagging can be done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Please go through this link:
[Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application](https://web.archive.org/web/20130228124515/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx#S1)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is about State Management in ASP.NET. What you have actually listed is Server Side state management options.

You can made a choice of which to use depending on your requirement or functionality.

I will recommend you do some background reading on MSDN regarding State Management. I am not sure which answer you need here as your query is a bit generic.

Here is a link to get you started... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open ended question.  Ass Julius said you need to learn more about the different ways you can store information.  For example, Application is used when you want to store information on the initial startup of the site and make it available to all users.  Session is for a single user so you may have many sessions open depending on how many users you have online at that time.  Cache is also a way you can store information on the server.  All of these are stored on the server so if you have hundreds of users online at the same time, server memory will be consumed holding all this information.  Rule of thumb is to try to be conservative when storing information in these locations.  Personally, I rarely use application and also try to limit my use of session to when it makes sense.  If I were to write an app that used crystal reports as you are, I would probably use sql to store the paramaters of the report and generate the report from the parameters but it depends entirely on the needs of the user using the app.

You can find a wealth of infomation on this subject on line.  Hopefully this will give you some information.